# How to find date using moment in mongoose with date type

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, momentjs

I want to search by date type in mongo db I've a problem that when I use moment It's change my default date so I don't understand why It change my date with same code

Here is what I try

```
    let params = {}
    let date = "2020-05-27" //I send it in String Type

    const newDate = new Date(date)
    const start = moment(newDate).startOf('day')
    const end = moment(newDate).endOf('day')
    console.log(newDate)
    console.log(start._d, end._d)
    Object.assign(params, { updatedAt: { $gte: start, $lte: end } })
    await Order.find(params)
```

when I send first request It's return the right date and collect defaut but after I send 1 more request my `start._d`   change value while my date is the same value

here is my first console.log

```
api              | 2020-05-27T00:00:00.000Z //date
api              | 2020-05-27T00:00:00.000Z (start.d)  2020-05-27T16:59:59.999Z (end.d)
```

here is my second console.log

```
  api            | 2020-05-27T00:00:00.000Z //date
api              | 2020-05-26T17:00:00.000Z(start.d) 2020-05-26T23:59:59.999Z(end.d)
```

as you see why my start.d -1 day while my date is same value at first time

after I send more request it will show same 2nd console.log

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why but I fix it by set all date by static

```
let newDate = moment(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
    // let start = moment(newDate).startOf('day')

    let start = newDate.toDate() // This will return a copy of the Date that the moment uses
    start.setHours(0)
    start.setMinutes(0)
    start.setSeconds(0)
    start.setMilliseconds(0)
    let end = newDate.toDate()
    end.setHours(23)
    end.setMinutes(59)
    end.setSeconds(59)
    end.setMilliseconds(59)
```

Comment: I guess `moment(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD').startOf('day')` and  `moment(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD').endOf('day')` could work equally well